# Can Universal Image Loader use different DiskCache for images?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using  [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for image loading, In the document I can't find a way to set different DiskCache for image display, the DiskCache directory is set by ImageLoader.getInstance().init(), which is global.

But I want to store some images in a separate DiskCache because I don't want it to be removed when LruDiskCache is full or cleared manually, I there anyway to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/92

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid **UIL** can't store specific image files intently. If I guess right, these images that you want to store in separate directory are used frequently. But, maybe you don't understand the mechanism of `LruDiskCache` which means "least recently used disk cache". Which means files used frequently would at the header of the queue all the time. So, if you use `LruDiskCache`, these images used frequently will be always stored in the disk and not be deleted or cleared. So, your requirement has been fulfilled when you use `LruDiskCache`.

Comment: thanks, But I know what LRU cache means and it doesn't meet my needs, because the images I want to store are not necessary the latest ones being visited.